# Semantically for HTML what do you think is the correct usage for the header tag

Tags: html, header, semantics

Here is a what i think to be a purely semantics question to settle an arguement that we are currently having. Which code snippet below is semantically correct or are they both correct. Which would you use?

```
<div id="header">
<header>

</header>
</div>
```

or:

```
<header>
<div id="header">

</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5 and modernizer or something like that then why would you have the div at all. Just style the header tag. If you are not able to use HTML5, then just stick with the div. Using both seems redundant.

Comment: I agree the div tag is unnecessary but it was used because styles on the header tag were giving us problems in IE. Even with modernizer.

Comment: One of the reasons I'm still avoiding HTML5 for many projects.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/

> According to the spec the header element represents a group of introductory or navigational aids. A header element typically contains the section’s heading (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup element), but can also contain other content, such as a table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos.

so for a site header (or for an introductory contents of a section element), the `<header>` element is fine and with more semantic than a regular `<div>`.

So your second example is more appropriate, but the id is not necessary for styling purpose. `header > div` can style it